# Handling exception in task

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library

I'm new to TPL.
I need to handle exception when the SendEmailAlert() method throws any error.Is the following code correct please?

```
public Task MyMethod()
{
    DoSomething();

    try
    {   
        string emailBody = "TestBody";
        string emailSubject = "TestSubject";

        Task.Run(()=> SendEmailAlert(arrEmailInfo));
    }
    catch (AggregateException ex)
                {
                    ex.Handle((e) =>
                       {
                           log.Error("Error occured while sending email...", e);
                           return true;
                       }
                       );
                }

}

private void SendEmailAlert(string[] arrEmailInfo)
{
    MyClassX.SendAlert(arrEmailnfo[0], arrEmailnfo[1]);
}
```

I forced an error from within SendEmailAlert() method.But the exception is not getting caught. Could someone advise?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you read this article on MSDN? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997415(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 1):

Your `Task.Run` runs in a different context (you would need a try/catch inside it; or check if the task is done). You could change to use async/await.

Example:

```
public async void MyMethod()
{
    try
    {
        await ExceptionMethod();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        // got it
    }
}

public async Task ExceptionMethod()
{
    throw new Exception();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.My call to SendEmailAlert is actually a "fire and forget" type .So I wont be using TAP design pattern.Please suggest any other approach.